# How to send file via Ajax call to Servlet

Tags: java, ajax, http-post, aem, ajaxform

I have an HTML form in AEM where I have to attach the files and the same files will be sent to one Rest API via Java Servlet.
I am calling the Java Servlet via Ajax and able to send other String data to Java Servlet but not able to send the file Array which contains the files attached to the HTML Form attachment option while submitting the Form. How can I get the file in Java servlet?

In JS

var myFile [] is what I am sending in a ajax call.

$.ajax({
url: /servletUrl,
type: 'post',
data: {
'myFile': myFile,
},
success: function(response){

}
});

In Java :

Enum paramObject  = request.getparameter();

When I put the object in HashMap and try to get the file, its type is coming as String not Object.
I am not sure where I am setting it as String.

Answer (score 1):

The servlet has to be able to process Multipart-Messages.

I do not know AEM, but in Jakarta / Java Enterprise Edition / JEE / J2EE:

1. you have to specifically add the @Multipart annotation to the servlet.
2. Now, open your browser, press F12 to go into debug details, and when you trigger the request, the Network tab will display alle the infos that are posted. Look up the name of the parameter, usually it's calles `file[]`
3. When handling the request in the servlet, you can use the `HttpServletRequest`'s `request.getParts()` method to find all parameter parts.
4. With `final Part filePart = request.getPart(pFileParamName);` and `final InputStream filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();` you will be able to access the data.

And this will probably be very similar in most servlet frameworks.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your reply. Actually the request.getParts() method is not available in SlingHttpServletRequest Interface which I am using. Now I am trying to convert the fileArray into Byte and try to convert it in Java.

Comment: Ah you're using Apache Sling. Should have said that. That makes it really easy: instead of the steps (3) and (4), you simply do: `byte[] dataBytes = request.getRequestParameter("file[]").get();`. Might do some checking in between, and maybe replace "file[]" with the real HTTP parameter name, as detected in step (2)